# How to hide the access keys of aws amazon productively in VagrantFile file

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I have Vagrant + Puppet project in a public Git
I recently had problems sending access_key_id public keys and
secret_access_key along with VagrantFile file. Crackers used AWS in my name.

Since then I remove the keys before updating the online git, and every time I need to add the keys in the file again if I want to manipulate the machines in aws.

Is there a way Vagrant Recognizing these variables using an environment variable? in a way that I can declare it outside the file and that every time you make "Vagrant UP" my machine automatically load the values ​​without the need to add in hand?

I use Ubuntu "12:04" in all machines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I think you can use environment variables for this:

- access_key_id -> `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`
- secret_access_key -> `AWS_SECRET_KEY`

You can see this in the [source code of `vagrant-aws`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/blob/master/lib/vagrant-aws/config.rb#L243).

Comment: That's exaclty what i'm looking for. I'll Figure how to use those lines with my environment, its a good start. Did you use it for yourself? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `.box` for your purpose and then ignore it from source control.

The `.box` is simply a tar archive that contains a file called `metadata.json` and, optionally, a `Vagrantfile` that gets merged with the one in your project directory.

You can find an useful example [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/tree/master/example%5fbox).

Comment: One of the features I have not yet explored is the question of customizable box, I honestly do not know how to use these boxes and still do not understand how this could actually help me.
What is the main advantage of using this method of Box? It is simply a repository of information, I can separate some information from the original VagrantFile and use for all machines, or am I missing something? Not the same thing as creating an image of the right machine?